# In which cases would I need to include validation-api in my project?

Tags: java, validation, maven

I'm checking a pom.xml of a Maven project, and I find this dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

So what are the cases (eventually frameworks?) which require adding this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

It is used to do the bean validation and not specific to any particular framework. It was developed as part of [JSR-303](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)